# How do I get the 'CheckedOutByUser' in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2010, 2013, check-out

I am updating a document and I try to check it out first. If it is already checked out by the current user I do nothing. If it is not checked out I check it out. For this I have the following code to get the checked out user -

```
var item = list.GetItemById(ItemId);
clientContext.Load(item.File, f => f.CheckedOutByUser.LoginName);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Since the document is not checked out the server side object is null and 'ClientObject.m_setAsNull' base member is set to true.
After checking out the document I try to get the 'CheckedOutByUser.LoginName' value using the following code

```
var item = list.GetItemById(ItemId);
clientContext.Load(item.File.CheckedOutByUser);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

This loads all the scalar properties of the 'User' object but the 'ClientObject.m_setAsNull' is not reset to false. Hence even though the LoginName property exists in the internal dictionarty I get the ServerObjectNullReferenceException.

Any idea how I should achieve what I want - Get the checkedout user when the value was null previously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that you have provided works for me in SharePoint 2013.

You could also try to retrieve Checkout User by Id:

```
context.Load(item);
context.ExecuteQuery();
var checkoutUserValue = item["CheckoutUser"] as FieldUserValue;
if (checkoutUserValue != null)
{
     var checkoutUser = context.Site.RootWeb.GetUserById(checkoutUserValue.LookupId);
     context.Load(checkoutUser);
     context.ExecuteQuery();
     Console.WriteLine(checkoutUser.LoginName);
}
```

### How to determine CSOM version

```
using (var context = new ClientContext(url))
{             
      context.ExecuteQuery();
      if (context.ServerVersion.Major == 16)
      {
           Console.WriteLine("SharePoint Online CSOM");
      }
}
```

Comment: Seems that this will not work against 2010. Can you confirm this? I get an error - Method "GetUserById" does not exist.
I want to maintain common code for 2010 and 2013 and use the 2013 assemblies

Comment: I conform that Web.GetUserById method is not available in SharePoint 2010 CSOM, so I believe this code only works in SPS 2013

Comment: do you know how I can get the SharePoint version via code so that I can have both pieces of code and can switch based on the version

Comment: The answer has been updated to demonstrate how to determine CSOM version, ClientContext.ServerVersion Property gets version of the current SharePoint Server http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientcontext.serverversion(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. My problem still is maintaining a single code base that works against both 2010 and 2013. Can I use the 2013 Client Object Model assemblies against SP 2010?

Comment: Can you go through the edit question and help me if possible?